# Is the main verb in the following sentence hidden or not?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Offenbar der Name der kleinen Stadt, die im Hintergrund angedeutet ist, ruiniert, zerfallen

I don't quite understand specifically the last two words of the sentence. I suppose that the word "ist" in this sentence is hidden, and ruiniert and zerfallen are adjectives following the relative clause "angedeutet ist". If so, why didn't the author write "die im Hintergrund ruiniert, zerfallen angedeutet ist", as I think it would be more grammatically correct.

Or could it be ruiniert the main verb? If so, the position of the zerfallen word is quite peculiar here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Glockenton eines Bahnhofs, bevor der Vorhang aufgeht. Dann die Inschrift: Güllen. Offenbar der Name einer kleinen Stadt, die im Hintergrund angedeutet ist, ruiniert, zerfallen.

Those are stage directions, or rather, a description of the stage setting and you wouldn't necessary expect full sentences here. Actually, there is no main verb in all of those "sentences" - Simply omitted.

> A train station's bell sound before the curtain opens. The signboard: Güllen. The name of a small town, apparently, hinted in the background, ruined, derelict.